# How to use time series model for data from multicolumn csv file

Tags: r

I've a csv file which has data logged for over 1 month time period. The 1st column is timestamp and rest of the columns are the values of different variables W. R. T the timestamp.
I want to create forecast using R programming, what a particular column value may look like in the next month based on the data that is available. The log file data sample is as shown below. The csv file has 5000 such entries.

| Timestamp | var1 | var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 08 29 00:00:00:928 | 7.58 | 480 |
| 2020 08 29 00:00:17:828 | 7.93 | 430 |

I want to predict the value of var1 in the coming month.

Please help.

Below is my code snippet in R

```
    library(pmml) 
    library(tidyverse)
    library(ggplot2)

    data <- read.csv("C:/Users/myprofile/Desktop/test 
    logs/test2.csv")
    data[['Timestamp']] <- as.POSIXct(data[['Timestamp']],
                               format = "%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S:%OS")
    colnames(data) <- c("Timestamp","var1")
    head(data)

    cpi <- ts(data$var1, frequency = 12, start = c(2020, 08))


    # Make the DataFrame
    tidy_data <- data.frame(
    date = seq(as.Date("2020-08-01"), as.Date("2020-9-01"), by = 
    "month"),
    cpi = cpi)
    tidy_data
   # Make the plot
   p <- ggplot(tidy_data, aes(x=date, y=cpi)) +
   geom_line(color="red", size=1.1) +
   theme_minimal() +xlab("") +ylab("var1") +
   ggtitle("Variable", subtitle = "From Aug 2020 Until Sept 2020")
   p
   # Get the statistical summary
   # Returns data frame and sort based on the CPI
   tidy_data %>%
   arrange(desc(cpi))
   tidy_data %>%
   arrange(cpi)
```

Output

| Timestamp | var1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-08-01 | 4.43 |
| 2020-08-01 | 4.43 |
| 2020-08-01 | 4.43 |
| 2020-09-01 | 4.41 |
| 2020-09-01 | 4.41 |
| 2020-09-01 | 4.41 |

Comment: SO is not a "write me some code"-site... You will have to show your own efforts in coding, and ask specific questions. The question above is likely too broad, and will/might be closed soon. That said; take a look at the `prophet`-package.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.